# Retrieving a list of nested groups within a Google Group

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am currently working with the google directory admin SDK specifically with groups and group memberships. I am looking to retrieve a list of nested groups within a group.
For example:

```
pdl_world@domain.tld might have pdl_emea@domain.tld, pdl_namer@domain.tld etc.
```

I know that I can iterate through a groups members and check each type using **.getType()** method. This seems inefficient for what I am looking to achieve (a list of nested groups).

Is there a method to achieve the above without iterating through all members and checking their type?

*SOLUTION:*

I was unable to find a solution out of the box from the API, in the end I wrote a custom recursive routine to loop through the group members detecting each as per type (GROUP/USER).

Comment: Is you question is to know the type of a member in a group? you can send this request GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members/memberKey in the response you will get both role and type. You can also retreive all the group members at a time. If your question in different, please explain it clearly

Comment: Hi Sgc, My main goal was to find all sub groups within a google group. In a given situation all i would have is the root group email address. In essence I would like to find all group members that are themselves groups  without having to loop through every member and checking their type.